# Does Html.ActionLink() post the form data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi a want form data to be availble in another action of same controller.

is it possible ? or is there any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActionLink is a anchor tag, so that doesn't post unless you do some javascript tricks.

Like how the LinkButton control in clasic asp.net workes.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in your subject: no.

To answer how do you get a form to post to different actions depending on the button that is clicked: you could change the action attribute of the form using javascript depending on the link/button clicked.

But maybe you mean you just want to post a form to a different action than what is used to  render the form, then just output your own form tag using the url helper for the action attr.

Or, a non javascript solution would be to always have the form posted to the same action using different buttons and then decide what to do depending on the name of the button (a param named after the button clicked will have a value in your action method)