# asp.net mvc actionlink difficulties

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have an actionlink in my view

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("action","controller") %>
```

the action has a `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` atttribute, and the lactionlink doesn't work.

how to make it work by "POST"??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To post to an action I use this JavaScript function:

```
function postToUrl(path, params, method) 
{
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default, if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for (var key in params) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);    // Not entirely sure if this is necessary
    form.submit();
}
```

It creates html form, so you don't have to create it in view code. this way you can use:

```
<button onclick="postToUrl('/Controller/Action');">Link</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

an ActionLink is just creates an anchor tag

```
<a href="url">link text</a>
```

This is inherently a GET verb.  To do a POST, you must wrap the actionlink inside a form tag and you can override the click function with some jQuery.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("action","controller"))
       { %>
   <%= Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "action","controller") %>
<% } %>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

        $("a").click(function() {
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: +1, but is it possible that you want `$(this).closest('form')` instead of `.parents` ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry mate, can't be done: take a look at the accepted reply here [Does Html.ActionLink() post the form data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688722/does-html-actionlink-post-the-form-data) and read a bit about the  tag here http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_a.asp

Answer (score 0):

Another option with no JS is to use a submit button instead of a link. The button can be styled into anything with CSS.

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller") {%>
  <button type="submit">text</button>
<%}%>
```